# URL Alias for Taxonomy for multiple child terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I am having a problem setting up the url alias for a vocabulary with recurring child terms.
So for instance the vocabulary consists of categories and locations.

- Category 01

  - All
  - Location 01
  - Location 02
- Category 02

  - All
  - Location 01
  - Location 02
- Category 03

  - All
  - Location 01
  - Location 02

At the moment I have 2 separate vocabularies of event categories and event locations.
For the node url I have setup the alias as

```
events/[node:field_event_category]/[node:field_event_location]/[node:field-event-start:value:custom:Y-m-d]-[node:title]
```

Now where I am stuck is setting up the url alias for the category and location.

Can anyone help with the best way to setup the vocabulary and url aliases? - Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm seeing, you're wanting to represent your 2 different taxonomies as a path hierarchy, but not a taxonomy hierarchy (i.e. Category terms don't have Location child terms). So you're looking to create something like:

- `events/` : All Events
- `events/X`: Events in Category X
- `events/X/Y`: Events in Category X & Location Y

Pathauto cannot create mixed-vocab url aliases however, so for a path hierarchy you can [create a page view](http://paralleldevs.com/blog/view-using-contextual-filters-multiple-taxonomy-vocabularies) with a couple of contextual filters, one for Category & another Location. The linked example should walk you through how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the link and your advice.  I have my views working so that it works as almost as expected.  

The problem I have now though is getting the location taxonomy term linking to the correct path.  So if I am in category 1 is there a way to for the location vocabulary to take that into account?

So it goes:
 **events** (shows all categories)/ **category 1** (shows all events in category 1, with a top menu of location terms)/ **location 1** (shows all events with category 1 and location 1)

Comment: Perhaps a separate block view of the events' unique locations tags with the same contextual filter will get you there.

Comment: I have a separate block pulling in the locations, however the url's don't match the required pattern; so don't link to the correct place.

Would re-writing the url contained in the taxonomy term in the view be a way of solving it or would that cause SEO issues?

Comment: Yup, that could get you there. Solve your problem first, worry about the SEO later (you can use the metatag module to get around any issues there).